# csharp Value of '01/01/0001 00:00:00' is not valid how to handle?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (File.Exists(settingsFile))
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(settingsFile);
                if (lines.Length > 0)
                {
                    trackBarHours.Value = Convert.ToInt32(optionsfile.GetKey("trackbarhours"));
                    trackBarMinutes.Value = Convert.ToInt32(optionsfile.GetKey("trackbarminutes"));
                    trackBarSeconds.Value = Convert.ToInt32(optionsfile.GetKey("trackbarseconds"));
                    savedMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(optionsfile.GetKey("milliseconds"));
                    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(optionsfile.GetKey("timetargetvalue"));
                    richTextBox1.Text = optionsfile.GetKey("result");
                }
            }
```

because the key "timetargetvalue" is not yet created in the settingsFile because i didn't saved it yet for the first time the value of the key of "timetargetvalue" is  '01/01/0001 00:00:00'

in that case that there is no yet the key hwo can i handle the datetime exception ?

dateTimePicker1 is a DateTimePicker control.

the exception is on the line :

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(optionsfile.GetKey("timetargetvalue"));
```

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '01/01/0001 00:00:00' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.
Parameter name: Value'

what should i check against of so it will not throw the exception ?

Comment: `if (DateTime.TryParse([Some string], out DateTime dtm) && dtm >= dateTimePicker1.MinDate) dateTimePicker1.Value = dtm;` -- Not clear what you want to set the DTP's Value to in case the string fails validation or returns an incompatible value

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a `Struct` such as `DateTime` that does not have any value we need to consider that this is not a `class` and can not be set to null. It must always have some value. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0)

The exception mentions in a round about way that the range of acceptable values is between `dateTimePicker1.MinDate` and `dateTimePicker1.MaxDate` so one option is to check if your value is within this range. But it's unlikely to be the best option. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

I'm pretty sure that `DateTime` default value is equal to that of `DateTime.Min` but if you really wanted to check if the value is default then I would suggest comparing it to `default(DateTime)` would be better.

This pretty much covers the use of `DateTime` and value defaults when null is not an option. Which brings up a possibly more desirable option. Encapsulation.

We could instead encapsulate the `DateTime` struct into a `Nullable` class. The encapsulating class will be nullable and will also be able to present the encapsulated value through a property called `Value`. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

There are two ways to declare such a `Nullable` class, both of which compile to the same thing:

```
Nullable<DateTime> myNullableDate = null;
DateTime? anotherNullableDate = null;
```

Since the `DateTime` is encapsulated in a `Nullable` object we can start using a null reference check. We can also call a method on `Nullable` called `HasValue` which returns a `bool` (True if it has a value).

EDIT: I notice that you're not doing any checks before trying to parse the `DateTime` and then directly setting it into the `DateTimePicker.Value` which can accept a null value. (although setting null won't clear a previously set value).

As such perhaps what you might want to do is handle the scenario a bit better and then use a `DateTime.TryParse()` instead. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-7.0)

e.g. (not the most optimized code, but I think it's easier to follow along in a more verbose form)

```
private DateTime? LoadDateFromOptions(string key)
{
    var rawValue = optionsfile.GetKey(key);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawValue))
    {
        return null;
    }

    DateTime dateValue;
    bool isSuccess = DateTime.TryParse(rawValue, out dateValue);

    if (isSuccess)
    {
        return dateValue;
    }
    else 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then instead of having that exception you can load the value optionally a bit more like this:

```
var timeTarget = LoadDateFromOptions("timetargetvalue");
if (timeTarget != null)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = timeTarget;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTimePicker.Value` must be above `DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime`, which is 'January 1, 1753'.

When you haven't set the `timetargetvalue`, it will resolve to '01/01/0001 00:00:00', as you have seen, which is too early.

So you need to check the value before assigning it to `DateTimePicker.Value`.

You can do it like this:

```
DateTime tempDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(optionsfile.GetKey("timetargetvalue");
dateTimePicker1.Value = tempDateTime >= DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime ? tempDateTime : DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime;
```